# Angularjs - FF displays {{ }} tags when navigating within page, Chrome doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I tried different methods to hide that content section altogether when loading and got it to work for initial page load, but when I move around within the page, it still shows the tags.

Any ideas?

You can check it here (click on some games on similar games section under the primary section):
http://vivule.ee/22

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS strategy to prevent flash-of-unstyled-content for a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074673/angularjs-strategy-to-prevent-flash-of-unstyled-content-for-a-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-cloak to solve this issue

You can put it on the specific level you want to cloak or at the top level such as body to html tag. The effect propagates downward. For example if it is on the body tag, all tags under the body tag will be cloaked

```
<body ng-cloak> 
    <div>{{variable}}</div> //cloaked
</body>
```

Comment: So even though there's a flagged duplicate question with this *exact same answer*, you felt the need to add it again?