# Why the html page doesn't load properly?

Tags: html, angularjs, pageload

I'm starting using Angularjs. I have a simple project (HTML + javascript/Angular js). When I visualize the HTML file on my browser I see a second hidden elements. Do you maybe know the reason? How can I solve this?

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS strategy to prevent flash-of-unstyled-content for a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074673/angularjs-strategy-to-prevent-flash-of-unstyled-content-for-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the way Angular works. I guess that you are able to see the skeleton of angular (something like {{"your variable"}}) for a second and then the data is rendered to it. 
Your angular scripts are called once the page is loaded, so the delay in fetching data from server by your $http.get() methods causes the elements to appear without data.
Thankfully, AngularJS has a simple solution to the problem in the form of ng-cloak directive. Refer the documentation for details.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak